# What data do accelerometers really return?

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

If I put my phone on the table, there is no acceleration. The phone feels gravity, yes. But no acceleration. However, the accelerometer shows 1g "acceleration" in z-axis. Is it therefore rather a gravity sensor? If no, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

The earth gravitational force, is - like the name says - a force. Means:

`Fg = m * a`

and the acceleration sensor in your phone is measuring the acceleration

`a = Fg/m`

Because of the principle of a MEMS acceleration sensor

[image]
<sub>(source: [sensorsmag.com](http://www.sensorsmag.com/files/sensor/nodes/2009/5852/Figure1.gif))</sub>

it detects a force.

You have two different accelerations in Android (and in iOS):

- [Accelerometer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel)
- [Linear Acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-linear)

The latter one is without gravity.